# Class method not executing recursively

Tags: python, recursion

I have this class method I have written for traversing a graph object, but when it reaches the line I commented #HERE!! it doesn't seem to execute it. When I run the debugger the if statement beforehand returns true, and it reaches the recursive call however it treats it as if nothing is there. Am I using the wrong syntax for recursively calling within a class method?

```
    def dfs(self, start):
        
        start_vert = self.vert_list[start]
        start_vert.set_color("gray")
        yield start_vert.label
        for vertex in self.vert_list.values():
            vertex.set_color("white")

        for nbr in start_vert.get_neighbors():
            next_vert = self.vert_list[nbr]
            if next_vert.color == "white":
                self.dfs(next_vert.label) #HERE!!
        start_vert.set_color("black")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are writing is a **generator**, not a simple class method - you can see this by the `yield` keyword inside the method.

Your generator is not doing anything with the values that the recursive call generates.

What you probably wanted to do, was to iterate over those values, maybe this:

```
if next_vert.color == "white":
    for label in self.dfs(next_vert.label):
        yield label
```

It is not possible to know exactly, without you stating the algorithm that you're working on.

Comment: Or just `yield from self.dfs(next_vert.label)` instead of the `for loop`.

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly the problem, there was no yield from the recursive calls. yield from worked perfectly in my case!